# Need to use Volume Shadow Copy Service in 32/64 bit QT C++ program

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, mingw, volume-shadow-service

I have a couple questions about using Volume Shadow Copy Service for my QT C++ program.

1. I read that in order to use VSS you must be running native 32/64 bit
   no WOW64 supported.  So this means I need to compile my program in
   whatever bits Windows is using on the computer where the program exe is running correct?
2. Do I need to use MSVC or can I do this using MinGW?
3. If I need MSVC how do I do a static build for 32 and 64 bit?  I found the first 4 links on google for "qt msvc static build" but they all vary a little bit so I'm wondering which is the best to use.
4. Also for either MSVC or MinGW do I need to include VSS libraries in the project?  I need to get the VSS SDK correct?  How do I integrate such into the program?  I already know the code to use.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

1. That is correct, the program must be compiled to match the target OS's architecture.
2. Since most of the VSC API is COM, I don't really see how trying to do this using MinGW would be better.
3. In Visual Studio, all you need to do is to include the VssApi lib, i.e.
   `#pragma comment (lib, "VssApi.lib")`
4. All you really need are the VSS specific headers. This also really depends on the OS your're targeting. If you plan on supporting say, Windows XP, you'll need the XP specific SDK.

Some reading: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923636(v=ws.10).aspx